# Custom array formatting with JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, ruby

So, I have a ruby script to dump RPG Maker XP data files into JSON, and it works pretty well. I use the JSON gem's pretty_generate method to parse the data into JSON, and I'm running into an issue with map data. As it's a large 3D array, (An array with three arrays inside it that each contain several arrays) pretty_generate spills it out as a large column. I'd much prefer to format the arrays instead as large blocks for readability. How would I go about doing that, while maintaining pretty_generates' format? I'd ideally only want it to apply to one specific array as well, how would I do that?

**Long format**

```json
"elements": [
   [
      [
         636,
         636,
         636,
         636,
         636,
       ], 
       [
         ...  
  ],
  [
     [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        ...
```

[Long format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezdUE.png)

**Block format**

```json
"elements":
[
 [[636,636,636,636,...],
  [636,636,636,636,...],
  ...]],
 [[0,0,0,0,...],
  [0,0,0,0,...],
  ...]],
 [[0,0,0,0,...],
  [0,0,0,0,...],
  ...]],
]
```

[Block format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq9Mb.png)

Comment: You can write your own JSON serializer, sure. It won't be easy to make it feature-complete, but if you just need to handle numbers and arrays of numbers, won't be that bad.

Comment: I can, but it wouldn't be very fun or practical to do so imo. 
Worst case scenario I could just turn the lowest level of arrays into strings and then back again to achieve what I'm looking for, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is for data exchange; pretty printers are for people. I wouldn't spend a lot of time on changing the serializer; instead, focus on how you want the deserialized data to display to a *person*, and then think carefully about whether displaying raw arrays or JSON data to a person even makes sense.

As just a singular example, [Kernel#pp](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) does a find job of displaying arrays. Consider:

```rb
array = 
  [
    [
      [
        636,
        636,
        636,
        636,
        636,
      ]
    ]
  ]

pp array
#=> [[[636, 636, 636, 636, 636]]]
```